# SharePoint Online List Headings: How to remove?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

SharePoint 2013, Custom List designed to work as an FAQ.  I've set up a grouped view and hidden all the columns bar one.

This list and view are embedded in a wiki page and I'd like to remove the remaining header as shown in the screenshot below.  Now I appreciate that "let me Google this for you" may be a valid response but the few JS / CSS snippets I've tried haven't yielded results as they've been written for different versions of SharePoint.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-vhltr { 
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Just add this to a script editor web part to the page, and all the column headers will be hidden.

Comment: I've added via the "Insert Snippet" web part but hasn't worked.  Is placement important?  Or is the fact I'm using a grouped view likely to render different CSS?

Comment: I would actually put the above inside a jQuery document.ready function, so it over-writes it after the DOM has loaded rather than interfering with the MS order of how CSS etc loads, which can sometimes be a wildcard factor.

Comment: Also it goes without saying you should View Source on the page in question and find the right element to make sure you've got the right CSS class. If you can do it on the basis of a HTML ID attribute rather than class so much the better but I get the feeling that won't be possible in this case.

Comment: All sound logic Thomas and to be taken on board.  Cheers for the pointers.